# Complex sql query with inner and left join with having and EXTRACT

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im getting this error from my query:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "cc" LINE 2: ... tt.sourceupdated_at having EXTRACT(DAY FROM max(cc.source_... ^

I'm stuck with this, please help me.

```sql
select count(*) AS full_count, (array_agg(id))[1:5] from (
    select distinct tt.id, tt.sourceupdated_at from (
        select t.id as id, t.sourceupdated_at from tickets_ticketagent as ta 
            inner join tickets_ticket as t on t.reference_id = ta.ticket_id 
            inner join users_agent as ua on ua.reference_id = ta.agent_id and ua.status = 1 
            inner join users_user as u on u.id = ua.user_id and u.status = 1  
            left join tickets_cleancomments as cc on cc.ticket_id = t.reference_id and cc.status = 1  
                where t.status in (1,2) and ta.agent_id = ANY( ARRAY[398290723973, 404958111713]::bigint[] )  
                group by t.id having count(distinct cc.comment_id) <= 6
    ) as tt 
    group by tt.id, tt.sourceupdated_at  
    having EXTRACT(DAY FROM max(cc.source_created_at) - min(cc.source_created_at)) > 10 
    order by tt.sourceupdated_at desc 
) as a
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The above query won't run on both...) Or perhaps Postgresql?

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions correctly. This was unreadable before I edited it.

Comment: my sql, query is running fine when i'm removing `having EXTRACT(DAY FROM max(cc.source_created_at) - min(cc.source_created_at)) > 10 `

Comment: Are you really sure it did run on MySQL before you added the having clause?!?

Comment: yes, its running on myWebSql

Comment: I'm getting error ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table " .. while add having clouse

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[1:5] from (
    select distinct tt.id, tt.sourceupdated_at from (
        selec' at line 1"

Comment: when i;m removing `having EXTRACT` then it works fine. I'm not an SQL expert.
Please help me, i'm getting error `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table`

Comment: I think you are using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL -HTH ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL! because you have many PostgreSQL functions in your query.
So I create a sample fiddle based on your query with some modifications [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70401/4) that works fine.
I think you can use it.

Now explain some tips about your query:

1. [you have an error in line 9](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70401/6):
   because you don't have `t.sourceupdated_at` after `group by`.
2. when you want to add a field in outer selects you need to add them in inner select statement. So, first add `source_created_at` in inner select (+ after group by) [like this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70401/10).
3. And don't forget that now you should use `tt` as alias of table instead of `cc`.

final query:

```
select count(*) AS full_count, (array_agg(id))[1:5] from (
    select distinct tt.id, tt.sourceupdated_at from (
        select t.id as id, t.sourceupdated_at, cc.source_created_at from tickets_ticketagent as ta 
            inner join tickets_ticket as t on t.reference_id = ta.ticket_id 
            inner join users_agent as ua on ua.reference_id = ta.agent_id and ua.status = 1 
            inner join users_user as u on u.id = ua.user_id and u.status = 1  
            left join tickets_cleancomments as cc on cc.ticket_id = t.reference_id and cc.status = 1  
                where t.status in (1,2) and ta.agent_id = ANY( ARRAY[398290723973, 404958111713]::bigint[] )  
                group by t.id, t.sourceupdated_at, cc.source_created_at
                having count(distinct cc.comment_id) <= 6
    ) as tt 
    group by tt.id, tt.sourceupdated_at  
    having EXTRACT(DAY FROM max(tt.source_created_at) - min(tt.source_created_at)) > 10
    order by tt.sourceupdated_at desc 
) as a
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, but cc id different, and tt is different.

Comment: @MrSingh In my query both are similar, but if you think you should use `cc` then you should using it in inner select like [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70401/13). -HTH ;)